# How do I escape curly braces in Asp .Net MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I'm trying to bind a data attribute as follows:

```
@Html.Label("test", new { data_test = "{{vm.test}}" })
```

When rendered, what I see is:

```
<label data-test for="test">test</label>
```

How do I escape the curly braces so that they're rendered on the page?  Some things a I've tried are:

- {{{{vm.test}}}}
- \\{\\{vm.test\\}\\}

Comment: So you want an output of `<label data-test="{{vm.test}}" for="test">test</label>` ?

Comment: Or do you want the value of `vm.test` to appear such as if vm.test has a value of "blah" then `<label data-test="blah" for="test">test</label>` ?

Comment: I tested the first scenario and it works fine, you can see in the inspector that you get `data-test="{{vm.test}}"`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hWYlqI  Tested using Chrome

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for - `data-test="{{vm.test}}`.  Not sure why I'm not getting the same output.  Only thing I can think of is a project/web.config setting that I'm not aware of.  Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Sometimes the browser will mess with your DOM.  What you see in a browser inspector is the result of parsing your HTML, and it will *fix* things like non-matching quotes or tags. Use the network tab in the browser to see the actual response to view the raw HTML before it is parsed, check to see if the data attribute is present there. If you have any stray characters, they might be causing a syntax issue, and your attribute value is getting lost when the browser does its best to fix the syntax.

Comment: Working fine here, with ASP.NET MVC 4 and IE 11 (and Chrome, too)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display the curly braces, as when you're explaining handlebar logic and you don't need any other constructs:

Code:

```
<note>Example: @("{{object.exampleField}}")</note>
```

Displayed:

```
Example: {{object.exampleField}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried with @: and other ways to scaped those...

Answer (score 0):

Inside a code block, you cannot use `@` characters to create more code blocks.
something like:

```
@Html.Label("test", new { data_test = "{{@vm.test}}" })
```

Answer (score 0):

To write curly braces "{}" in razor use the combination of "at" and "colon".
Example: **@:{**

I had just figured it out while using handle bars.

And to write "@" use one more "at" sign.

Example: **@@**

I hope it helps the new ones who are looking for it!